# NSArray value to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsarray

I have an NSArray declared like this in my ViewDidLoad
`animalz = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rabbit",@"deer",@"ox", @"horse", @"cow", nil];` and I have a UIView subclass that I wrote which takes an NSString and rearranges it. The user presses a button and the number associated with the button is the number in the array that I need (Ex. if the number is three then I would need the value "horse" but if the button was 4 then I would need "cow"); Currently these numbers come in the form of long int and I can't get the corresponding value in the nsarray. I tried doing:

```
    selectedani //this is the long int that represents the button
    int indexani = [animalz objectAtIndex:selectedani];
    NSString *anistr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexani];
    [self rearrange:btistr];
```

This doesn't give me any compiler warnings or errors but when I press the button , the app crashes. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the call stack on the crash?  What's the output in the debugger console?

Comment: This is just plain wrong: ` int indexani = [animalz objectAtIndex:selectedani];`  objectAtIndex will always return an object pointer (or nil).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield the error is: Thread 1: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
selectedani //this is the long int that represents the button
NSString *anistr = [animalz objectAtIndex:selectedani];
[self rearrange:anistr];
```

Comment: I tried this and my app crashed again. I got the error "Thread 1: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: And what have you done to debug the crash?  Have you set breakpoints in your code and stepped through this code to see if you get through it?

Comment: well, when I have just the long int it works fine. Only when I try to access the array does it not work.

Comment: @user2510806 - It doesn't work with the int.  It maybe doesn't crash, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

`animalz` is an array of `NSString` objects, but when you call `[animalz objectAtIndex:selectedani]`, you assign the result to an int.

Comment: how could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you assigned ***selectedani*** before you used it? If not then you shouldn't use selectedani. It maybe the memory location or some other property of the button which may vary.

```
[animalz objectAtIndex:selectedani]
```

is returned an object, casting this object to an int not what you want and of course it's not an index too.

What can you do? Assign a tag number to the corresponding button dynamically, like

```
button.tag = 1;//or something like it
```

Then in the **IBAction** method retrieve the tag and use it to parse your array.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *pressedBtn = (UIButtton *)sender;
  NSString *anistr = [animalz objectAtIndex:pressedBtn.tag];

  //do what you want to do with the string
  [self rearrange:anistr];
}
```

In this case, declare ***animalz*** as an iVar or property.